# Chromium Font Colour

Tags: fonts, chromium

My Chromium fonts are a bit off. I had a problem with the fonts themselves and the size. I managed to just select different fonts under the "Preferences" menu in Chromium and to change the size as well. However, I am still faced with the issues of colour. Fonts that are normally white in other browsers for example, are a dull gray and almost impossible to read on certain backgrounds (blue for example). Is there any way to remedy this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Due to the way web pages are composed these days (with a premium on appearance rather than on function and with the rather thoughtless use of background images to convey information), accessibility for those with special requirements is often an issue. There are [accessibility extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/ext/22-accessibility?hl=en-US) available at the Chrome Web Store that should, in all probability, work with Chromium, and that may help but there's always the chance that there'll be problems with certain pages. You'll have to be aware of that possibility.

Two extensions may be considered:
[Change Colors](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jbmkekhehjedonbhoikhhkmlapalklgn?hl=en-US) and [PlainClothes](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kleiknekfnnaaibjhlamidabhmckbddc?hl=en-US)